# Error when trying to deploy Qt application using shared libraries

Tags: c++, linux, qt, deployment, raspberry-pi

I tried to deploy a qt application using the shared library approach described here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html (5th headline)

When I go to my project folder and type "make clean" I get this error: "make: *** No rule ro make target 'clean'. Stop"

What is the problem here?

Also: The documentation states: "We assume that you already have installed Qt as a shared library, which is the default when installing Qt, in the /path/to/Qt directory."

How can I check if I installed Qt as a shared library?

I wrote the application in C++ using the Qt Creator on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian Jessie. I want to deploy it so I can use it on another Raspberry that has minimal functionality without desktop-gui or qtcreator installed. I am using Raspbian Jessie Lite on that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running **make** you should have **Makefile** there. If you don't, run **qmake** to generate one. If qmake fails, you've done something really wrong with .pro file.